# .htaccess - if statement: host contains (not equals) subdomain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, apache2.4

I have these statements in my .htaccess, to match subdomains:

```
<If "req('Host') == 'subdomain.domain.com'"></If>
<If "req('Host') == 'subdomain.staging.domain.com'"></If>
```

How can I write these statements so that subdomains of these subdomains will also match:

```
s1.subdomain.domain.com
s1.subdomain.staging.domain.com
```

Something like this:

```
<If "req('Host') contains 'subdomain.domain.com'"></If>
<If "req('Host') contains 'subdomain.staging.domain.com'"></If>
```

Comment: Something like: `<If "%{HTTP_HOST} =~ m#(?:[^.]+\.)*subdomain(?:\.[^.]+)*\.domain\.com$#">`? PS: *contains* is the `=~` operator with strings as operands (eg: `<If "req('Host') =~ 'subdomain.domain.com'">`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for "regular expressions".

Your above examples would be converted into:

```
<If "req('Host') =~ /^(?:s1\.)?subdomain\.domain\.com$/">
<If "req('Host') =~ /^(?:s1\.)?subdomain\.staging\.domain\.com$/">
```

The more general version to accept *any* "subdomain" would be something like that:

```
<If "req('Host') =~ /^(?:.+\.)*subdomain\.domain\.com$/">
<If "req('Host') =~ /^(?:.+\.)*subdomain\.staging\.domain\.com$/">
```